# Debugging mbed os 5

Tags: debugging, mbed

I took a look at the mbed OS 5 and the corresponding mbed cli

I created first programs and programmed them via the binary drag and drop to the flash disk provided by the programmer (Using the GCC_ARM compiler, target is a NUCLEO_F429ZI). For serious projects this is not suitable as the device cannot be debugged this way.

As i can read from the mbed documentation the programmer also contains the CMSIS-DAP interface which can be used to program/debug the device.

For evaluation i would like to use a free IDE and use it for debugging. So i would choose Eclipse for this using the C/C++ version of it.

My question now is:

- How does the toolchain for a Windows / Linux machine look like?
- Does a professional toolchain even include the CMSIS-DAP or does one better use JTAG directly?
- What is the flow of programming / debugging over CMSIS-DAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TL;DR*:

1. Make sure to make a debug build (`mbed compile --profile ./mbed-os/tools/profiles/debug.json`).
2. Use the [OpenOCD Eclipse Plugin](http://gnuarmeclipse.github.io/debug/openocd/).

---

*A bit deeper:*

Most mbed boards can be programmed using [pyOCD](https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD) or [OpenOCD](http://openocd.org), these tools start up a GDB server to which GDB can then connect (via arm-none-eabi-gdb). (Almost?) every C++ IDE understands how to use GDB for debugging.

For the F429ZI you use OpenOCD, with the following parameters:

```
PATH_TO_OPENOCD/bin/openocd 
    -f PATH_TO_OPENOCD/scripts/board/stm32f4discovery.cfg 
    -f PATH_TO_OPENOCD/scripts/interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg 
    -c init -c "reset init"
```

You can then start up GDB and connect to localhost:3333 to interact with the device. For example, here's how to configure Visual Studio Code to [debug mbed boards](https://github.com/janjongboom/mbed-os-example-uvisor/blob/rpc-and-vscode/.vscode/launch.json).

If you want [semihosting](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_pge1358787046598.htm) messages (f.e. to debug uVisor), use netcat to connect to pyOCD/OpenOCD via: `nc localhost 4444` right after attaching the debugger.